# how to get backup two postgresql servers in virtual box

Tags: debian, postgresql

I'm new in postgresql and I am watching a video about it. In this video the teacher connect two real  debian servers and everything works fine. I have two debian servers in my virtualbox and my servers have bridge connection to my win10 host and their IPs are:

> server1: 192.168.43.39
>
> server2: 192.168.43.154

I have new user named ureplication in server1 with this command:

> CREATE USER ureplication WITH REPLICATION ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '123456';

and my configurations in server1:

> postgresql.conf:
>
> listen_addresses = '*'
>
> pg_hba.conf:(last line)
>
> host replication ureplication 192.168.43.154/24 md5

and finally try to have backup from server1 to server2 with:

> pg_basebackup -h 192.168.43.39 -p 5432 -U ureplicaton -D
> pg_1921684339_backup -Fp -Xs -P -R

and get this error in server2: is the server running on that host and accepting tcp/ip connections?

Comment: I don't know whether that'd be the content I'd enjoy as a video lecture, learning administration is so text-centric... but everyone learns differently. Anyway, what your teacher in the video doesn't tell you is that they shut down any firewall and network segmentation, and maybe they also forgot to mention that most installations of database servers will by default not accept connections from outside and need to be configured to do that. I'm not sure `listen_address = '*'` does that (and please make sure you never expose your database to the internet, accidentally).

Comment: (i.e., generally, I'd recommend *not* using `'*'`, but something like `'192.168.43.39,localhost'`) (and while we're at it, don't use `md5` as auth method. MD5 has **long** been cracked, and there's enough alternatives that just work as a drop-in replacement, e.g. `scram-sha-256`.)

Comment: Most importantly, have you restarted your server after the configuration changes were made? Can you ping server1 from server2 and vice versa?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your response and good explanations. yes I restarted my server and ping both servers from each other and even I tried to have ssh connection and everything was fine.

Comment: can you confirm the database is running?

Comment: @MarcusMüller what do you mean? how? pg_isready?

Comment: I mean, is the daemon started? What does the daemon log say? `journalctl --unit=postgresql`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I get it. I used to use systemctl status postgresql@14-main.service and I think both was fine yesterday but when I try it again now server1 's status was failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138396/discussion-between-saba-and-marcus-muller).